# node js mongoose model populate confusion

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-populate

My scenario is to query **getEmp_onId** from **model 1 (employee.js)** and that will populate the employee details from **model 2 (empdetails.js)**.

**Problem:**

When i run query on **model 1 (employee.js)** i get employee data but **NO populated data in it**

```
[
  {"_id": "552790d18d3a9810ee5c26c0",
    "username": "demo person"
    "email": "test@example.com"
  }
]
```

But shockingly when i directly run query on **model 2 (empdetails.js)** i get populated data from **model 1 (employee.js) !!**

```
[
  {"_id": "552ca14069303a15eda1bc95",
    "emp_id": {
        "_id": "552790d18d3a9810ee5c26c0",
        "username": "demo person"
        "email": "test@example.com"
    },
    "city": "demo city",
    "state": "demo state",
    "country": "demo country"
  }
]
```

Please can any one explain how mongoose models populate works?

**Model : 1**

```
employee.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var collection_name = 'employees';

var employee_schema = new Schema({
  _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId}, username: {type: String}, email: {type: String, unique: true},
  emp_details: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'empdetails'}
});

employee_schema.methods = {
  getEmp_onId: function(empid, cb) {
    this.model(collection_name)
    .find({ _id: empid })
    .populate('emp_details')
    .exec(function(err, res) {
      if(err) { cb(err, null); }
      else { cb(null, res); }
    });
  }
};
```

**Model : 2**

```
empdetails.js
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var collection_name = 'empdetails';

var schema = new Schema({
  _id: {type: Schema.ObjectId},
  emp_id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'employees'},
  city: {type: String}, state: {type: String}, country: {type: String}
});

schema.methods = {
  emp_details_by_id: function(empid, cb) {
    this.model(collection_name)
    .find({ emp_id: empid })
    .populate('emp_id')
    .exec(function(err, res) {
      if(err) { cb(err, null); }
      else { cb(null, res); }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: How are you saving the `employee` and `empdetail` models?

Comment: are you sure your `employees` document _has_ a reference to an `empdetails` document? There's no magic here, if you don't store a reference inside `emp_details` mongoose can't populate it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are saving employee first and saving details with employee id later. Which means, your details document have a reference to employee document but employee document has no reference back. You should do something like this:

```
employee = new employee_model({username: 'username', email: 'email'});
details = new detail_model({emp_id: employee.id, city: 'City'});
employee.emp_details = details.id;
employee.save();
details.save();
```